# how to instantiate a DataTable object

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am creating a web application in asp.net that runs a query and with the received data instantiates a datatable object and displays the data on the screen.

This is my backend:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDataForDataTable(int draw, int start, int length)
{
    OleDbConnection OLEConnectionSPHERA = new OleDbConnection();
    OLEConnectionSPHERA = Common.openConnOLEADODB(OLEConnectionSPHERA);

    string s_odlQuery = $"SELECT CODODL, FLAGAPERTO, DATAINIZIO, ORAINIZIO, PROGRESSIVO, DATAFINE, ORAFINE, DURATA, CODCDL, TURNO FROM S_ODL ORDER BY PROGRESSIVO OFFSET {start} ROWS FETCH NEXT {length} ROWS ONLY";

    OleDbDataReader s_odlRD = Common.executeQuery(s_odlQuery, OLEConnectionSPHERA);

    List<Oggetto> dati = new List<Oggetto>();
    int numRecord = 0;

    while (s_odlRD.Read())
    {
        numRecord++;
        try
        {
            Oggetto obj = new Oggetto();
            obj.cododl = s_odlRD.GetValue(s_odlRD.GetOrdinal("CODODL")).ToString();
            obj.flagaperto = s_odlRD.GetValue(s_odlRD.GetOrdinal("FLAGAPERTO")).ToString();
            obj.datainizio = s_odlRD.GetValue(s_odlRD.GetOrdinal("DATAINIZIO")).ToString();
            obj.orainizio = s_odlRD.GetValue(s_odlRD.GetOrdinal("ORAINIZIO")).ToString();
            obj.progressivo = s_odlRD.GetValue(s_odlRD.GetOrdinal("PROGRESSIVO")).ToString();
            obj.datafine = s_odlRD.GetValue(s_odlRD.GetOrdinal("DATAFINE")).ToString();
            obj.orafine = s_odlRD.GetValue(s_odlRD.GetOrdinal("ORAFINE")).ToString();
            obj.durata = s_odlRD.GetValue(s_odlRD.GetOrdinal("DURATA")).ToString();
            obj.codcdl = s_odlRD.GetValue(s_odlRD.GetOrdinal("CODCDL")).ToString();
            obj.turno = s_odlRD.GetValue(s_odlRD.GetOrdinal("TURNO")).ToString();

            dati.Add(obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    Common.closeConnOLEADODB(OLEConnectionSPHERA);

    var result = new
    {
        draw = draw,
        recordsTotal = numRecord, // Implementa questo metodo per ottenere il totale dei record
        recordsFiltered = numRecord, // Implementa questo metodo per ottenere il totale dei record dopo il filtraggio (se applicato)
        data = dati
    };

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

and this is my frontend:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="example" style="width:100%" class="display">
                
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>CODODL</th>
                        <th>FLAGAPERTO</th>
                        <th>DATAINIZIO</th>
                        <th>ORAINIZIO</th>
                        <th>PROGRESSIVO</th>
                        <th>DATAFINE</th>
                        <th>ORAFINE</th>
                        <th>DURATA</th>
                        <th>CODCDL</th>
                        <th>TURNO</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
            
        </div>
    </form>
<script>
$(function () {
var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Sph_table_00.aspx/GetDataForDataTable")%>';
var dataTable;


dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": pageUrl,
        "type": "POST",
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "dataType": "json",
        "data": function (d) {
            console.log(d);
            return JSON.stringify(d);
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        { data: 'cododl', name: 'CODODL' },
        { data: 'flagaperto', name: 'FLAGAPERTO' },
        { data: 'datainizio', name: 'DATAINIZIO' },
        { data: 'orainizio', name: 'ORAINIZIO' },
        { data: 'progressivo', name: 'PROGRESSIVO' },
        { data: 'datafine', name: 'DATAFINE' },
        { data: 'orafine', name: 'ORAFINE' },
        { data: 'durata', name: 'DURATA' },
        { data: 'codcdl', name: 'CODCDL' },
        { data: 'turno', name: 'TURNO' }
    ]
});
}
</script>
</body>
```

With this code below takes the data and sets the datatable properties such as draw, data, and recordsTotal. The problem is that even though the data arrives correctly the table is not filled.

[image]

Comment: try specifiying `dataSrc: 'data'` in ajax

Comment: according to https://datatables.net/manual/ajax - `dataType` and `data` seems unnecessary

Comment: Side notes: you need `using` on the connection and command, and you have an SQL injection issue. And instead of `s_odlRD.GetValue(s_odlRD.GetOrdinal("TURNO")).ToString()` you can shorten it to `s_odlRD["TURNO"].ToString()`

Comment: @RandRandom `dataSrc: 'data'` I tried but nothing changes. `datatype` and `data` I can't delete them, I have to pass the draw, start and length parameters

Comment: @Charlieface How can i solve the sql injection issue? and for `using` how should i use it?

Comment: `using `OleDbConnection OLEConnectionSPHERA =` and `using OleDbDataReader s_odlRD =` etc. Instead of injection use proper parameterization. I think OleDB uses positional `?` as the placeholders, so you have to add the parameters in the same order.